# Set second nested subform check box to true in Access VBA

Tags: vba

I have a form that has Work Orders, PK=OrderID. A subform that has the OrderDetails, PK=OrderDetailsID. And a subform on that subform that has OrderDetailAccessories, PK=OrderAccID.

When I set a check box on the main form to True, I want all the check boxes for the subform OrderDetails to change to True and set the CompDate to todays date AND all the check boxes for it's subform OrderDetailsAccessories to change to True and set the CompDate to today's date.

In my code, the recordset rs returns the records expected but I get an empty recordset for rs2. I stepped through the code and orddetid returns the correct value.

```vb
Private Sub IsComplete_AfterUpdate()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strItemComp As String
    Dim strAccComp As String
    Dim ordid As Long
    Dim orddetid As Long

    ordid = Me.txtOrdID
    strItemComp = "SELECT OrderDetailID, IsComplete, CompDate FROM tblOrderDetails WHERE OrderID = " & ordid
    strAccComp = "SELECT OrderAccID, IsComplete, CompDate FROM tblOrderAcc WHERE OrderDetailID = " & orddetid
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strItemComp)

    If Me.IsComplete = True Then
        If MsgBox("Marking main order complete will mark ALL items and accessories for this Order as complete!", vbYesNo, "Are you sure?") = vbYes Then
            Me!txtCompletionDate = Date
            rs.MoveFirst
            Do Until rs.EOF
                If rs!IsComplete = False Then
                    rs.Edit
                    rs!IsComplete = True
                    rs!CompDate = Date
                    rs.Update
                End If

                orddetid = rs.Fields("OrderDetailID").Value
                Debug.Print orddetid
                Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(strAccComp)
                If rs2.RecordCount > 0 Then
                    rs2.MoveFirst
                    Do Until rs2.EOF
                        If rs2!IsComplete = False Then
                            rs2.Edit
                            rs2!IsComplete = True
                            rs2!CompDate = Date
                            rs2.Update
                        End If
                        rs2.MoveNext
                    Loop
                End If

                rs.MoveNext
            Loop
            Me.Dirty = False
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Me.Undo
        End If
    Else
        Me.txtCompletionDate = Null
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.Dirty = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must update `strAccComp` for each record, something like:

```vb
If Me.IsComplete = True Then
    If MsgBox("Marking main order complete will mark ALL items and accessories for this Order as complete!", vbYesNo, "Are you sure?") = vbYes Then
        Me!txtCompletionDate = Date
        Me.Dirty = False

        Set rs = Me!NameOfSubformControl.Form.RecordsetClone
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            If rs!IsComplete = False Then
                rs.Edit
                rs!IsComplete = True
                rs!CompDate = Date
                rs.Update
            End If

            strAccComp = "SELECT OrderAccID, IsComplete, CompDate FROM tblOrderAcc WHERE OrderDetailID = " & rs!orddetid.Value
            Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strAccComp)
            If rs2.RecordCount > 0 Then
                rs2.MoveFirst
                Do Until rs2.EOF
                    If rs2!IsComplete = False Then
                        rs2.Edit
                        rs2!IsComplete = True
                        rs2!CompDate = Date
                        rs2.Update
                    End If
                    rs2.MoveNext
                Loop
            End If
            rs2.Close
            
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        rs.Close

    End If
End If
```